# Querying BigTable data with BigQuery: how to make a correct table definition file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I try to set up external tables for BigQuery, the source is BigTable. I can create a table but while executing a sql statment i get this error:

> Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 6.
> Error: Data between close double quote (") and field separator.

Most likely the table definition file is wrong. I spend the last day tinkering, but i don't find the problem. Can somebody point out the mistake i'm making?

thanks

my workflow:

- create definition file
- use command: bq mk --external_table_definition=gs://realtimecrypto-ostabprj/def.json test.test1
- in bigquery: SELECT * FROM `ostabprj.test.test1` LIMIT 1000

my table definition file:

I also tried different variations of it.

```
{
"sourceFormat": "BIGTABLE",
"sourceUris": [
    "https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/ostabprj/instances/cryptorealtime/tables/cryptorealtime"
],
"bigtableOptions": {
    "columnFamilies" : [
        {
            "familyId": "market",
            "type": "STRING",
            "encoding": "TEXT"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

The data in Bigtable looks like this:

(from this tutorial: https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/5570?locale=en&parent=catalog)

```
----------------------------------------
XRP/USD#bitfinex#1641740466459#3848397969954
  market:delta                             @ 2022/01/09-15:01:06.459000
    "459"
  market:exchangeTime                      @ 2022/01/09-15:01:06.459000
    "1641740466000"
  market:market                            @ 2022/01/09-15:01:06.459000
    "bitfinex"
  market:orderType                         @ 2022/01/09-15:01:06.459000
    "BID"
  market:price                             @ 2022/01/09-15:01:06.459000
    "0.74557"
  market:volume                            @ 2022/01/09-15:01:06.459000
    "50"
```

the guides i was using:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable#permanent-tables

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-table-definition#tabledef-bigtable

(links have been changed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a colleague has meanwhile found a way to solve the problem.
He also found a youtube video which covers most of my questions.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tW4h6-cQz9s

I made 2 fundamental mistakes:

- BigTable and BigQuery weren't on the same server (US and EU)
- The table definition file has to be uploaded with the console and not into a bucket

his solution for the table definition file looked like this:

- 'readRowKeyAsString' should be true

```
        "sourceFormat": "BIGTABLE",
        "sourceUris": [
            "https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/..."
        ],
        "bigtableOptions": {
            "readRowkeyAsString": "true",
            "columnFamilies": [
                {
                    "familyId": "market",
                    "columns":[
                        {
                            "qualifierString": "market",
                            "type":"STRING"
                        },
                        {
                            "qualifierString": "exchangeTime",
                            "type":"STRING"
                        },
                        {
                            "qualifierString": "delta",
                            "type":"STRING"
                        },
                        {
                            "qualifierString": "orderType",
                            "type":"STRING"
                        },
                        {
                            "qualifierString": "volume",
                            "type":"STRING"
                        },
                        {
                            "qualifierString": "price",
                            "type":"STRING"
                        }
                    ]
                } 
            ]
        }
    }
```

To use the whole thing in BigQuery a Dataview is necessary

```
CREATE VIEW Table.Dataview AS
SELECT
    rowkey,
    market.delta as ts,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(market.delta.cell)), "") AS delta,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(market.market.cell)), "") AS market,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(market.exchangeTime.cell)), "") AS exchangeTime,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(market.orderType.cell)), "") AS orderType,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(market.price.cell)), "") AS price,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(market.volume.cell)), "") AS volume
FROM Table.Data
```